# Passing a method as a parameter with zero or more parameters for the passed in method?

Tags: c#, triggers

I'm trying to code what I've called a 'trigger'. They take an object, a function and some kind of activation criteria. Once activated, it runs the method on that object.

[Here's a basic stripped down example.](http://pastebin.com/M6RXTAj1) It works as expected for now. An example usage would be:

```
SomeObject myObj = new SomeObject();
MyTrigger trigger = new MyTrigger(myObj, "Delete");
trigger.Activate(); // calls myObj.Delete();
```

Now where I've called `Invoke` with `null` is where parameters can normally go (I think). The problem I'm having is getting the 'zero or more paramters' as a single parameter in the function declaration. I need a thrid parameter when creating `MyTrigger` that would be the parameters to pass during the `Invoke`.

Or is there an even better way to do it? I.e. Can I somehow pass the object, the function call and the parameters as a single parameter? Maybe two parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use delegates.

```
// rewrite your trigger constructor like this
class MyTrigger<TTarget>
{
    public MyTrigger(TTarget target, Action<TTarget> action);
    public void Activate()
    {
        this._action(this._target);
    }
}

// now call it with or without parameters
SomeObject myObj = new SomeObject();
var trigger = new MyTrigger<SomeObject>(myObj, o => o.Delete(1234));
trigger.Activate();
```

You can also create a static helper class to make the creation code slightly simpler to write:

```
static class MyTrigger
{
    public MyTrigger<TTarget> Create<TTarget>(TTarget target, Action<TTarget> action)
    {
        return new MyTrigger<TTarget>(target, action);
    }
}

// now write the initialization code like this (you don't have to specify the type parameter anymore):
var trigger = MyTrigger.Create(myObj, o => o.Delete());
```

Comment: Delegates are something I've not used before. What's `TTarget`, just a way of saying `This will be a type`? Then `Action<TTarget>` means a method that can be found on type `TTarget`? The only part I don't think I can explain is the `o => o.Delete(1234)`.

Comment: `o => o.Delete(1234)` means that you are passing an anonymous method that will call `.Delete()` with argument `1234` on any object you pass to it. see the edited answer.

Comment: I was about to ask if the `Activate` code would be different too but you updated as I was typing. This definitely sounds like the correct way to do it. Thank you, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: In this case, assuming `MyTrigger` is immutable (don't pass a different/new `target` later on) and doesn't _need_ the generics, could even ditch the target/generics and execute a general `Action`: `new MyTrigger(() => myObj.Delete(1234))` (few big "ifs" there, but perhaps applicable, and Matthew will probably need a sense of closure)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I think the only "ifs" and closure I need is on the whole `=>` part. I've only used `=>` in PHP when dealing with `Key => Value` arrays. I don't understand this syntax in C# (and it's proving hard to Google) but I understand everything else that's going on!

Comment: @MatthewMcGovern Look up [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and [anonymous functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx)

Comment: `Create(o => o.Delete(1234);)` is the same as writing `void MyMethod(o) { o.Delete(1234); }` and `Create(this.MyMethod);`

Comment: @ChrisSinclair thanks for the links, I'll get to reading about this and delegates as they sound useful for what I'm doing. Knagis, thanks again for the help. When you word it like that it's very similar to passing an anonymous function in Javascript so it makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: @MatthewMcGovern It's fairly identical to anonymous functions in JavaScript. If you understand how those work you should be able to apply that knowledge directly to lambdas/anonymous methods in C#.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Excellent then! I was getting confused with the `o => o.Method` part but now I know it just means a function that does (in Laymens English): `Here's o, do Method on o` it all makes sense. I'm assuming, say something like: `(o, x) => {o.Method1; x.Method2;}` would also work fine (ignoring my trigger example now, just pretend the accepting function is set up to handle two objects).

Comment: @MatthewMcGovern Yes, you would just have to update the types to match (i.e. `Action<TTarget1, TTarget2> action`) and of course invoke the methods: `{ o.Method1(); x.Method2(); }` (you left out the parenthesis but I'm guessing that was just a typo)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) keyword:

```
public Trigger(object targetObject, string methodName, params object[] parameters)
{
    //"parameters" here will be an array of length 0 if no parameters were passed    
}

MyTrigger trigger = new MyTrigger(myObj, "Delete"); //no parameters
MyTrigger trigger = new MyTrigger(myObj, "Delete", param1); //one parameter
MyTrigger trigger = new MyTrigger(myObj, "Delete", param1, param2); //two parameters
```

But I prefer [Knagis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16546182/1269654) because it will also provide you compile-time safety (and likely the `Trigger` class will be *far* simplified and ditch any reflection that you probably have in there.)